# How can I write this MSSQL code in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guys I've written this MS SQL script with my awesome MS SQL skills, how can I get it to work in MySQL? It's failing on some of the string functions :( Don't know MySQL too well!

```
SELECT i.id as ID, e.code as EMPCODE, lower(e.email_address) as EMAIL
from load_incidents i , dim_employee e
WHERE
(     (i.involvedemail = e.email_address)
or    (replace(lower(e.preferred_name+e.last_name),' ', '') = replace(lower(i.involvedname),' ', ''))
or    (replace(lower(e.preferred_name+e.last_name),' ', '') like replace(lower(i.involvedname),' ', '')+'%')
or    (replace(lower(e.first_name+e.last_name),' ', '') = replace(lower(i.involvedname),' ', ''))
or    (replace(lower(e.first_name+e.last_name),' ', '') like replace(lower(i.involvedname),' ', '')+'%')
or    (replace(lower(e.employee_name),' ','') = replace(lower(i.involvedname),' ',''))
)
and charindex(' ',e.first_name) = 0
and (i.involvedemail= 'none available' or i.involvedemail is null or i.involvedemail = '')
UNION
SELECT i.id as ID, e.code as EMPCODE, lower(e.email_address) as EMAIL
from load_incidents i , dim_employee e
WHERE
(     (i.involvedemail = e.email_address)
or    (replace(lower(e.preferred_name+e.last_name),' ', '') = replace(lower(i.involvedname),' ', ''))
or    (replace(lower(e.preferred_name+e.last_name),' ', '') like replace(lower(i.involvedname),' ', '')+'%')
or    (replace(lower(left(e.first_name,charindex(' ',e.first_name)-1) + e.last_name),' ', '') = replace(lower(i.involvedname),' ',''))
or    (replace(lower(e.employee_name),' ','') = replace(lower(i.involvedname),' ',''))
)
and charindex(' ',e.first_name) > 1
and (i.involvedemail= 'none available' or i.involvedemail is null or i.involvedemail = '')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOUR problem is the `charindex` function, use locate (in place of charindex) for that purpose :

```
LOCATE(' ',e.first_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the functions are the same. Here's a list of [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I tried ***[Full Convert Enterprise](http://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/)*** with quite big success. Fast, easy and it did my job. Give it a try it may help you.

Also, You're probably best off doing this yourself to ensure everything is correct rather than relying on a third party tool (Also the additional benefit of understanding the differences between the two pieces of code).  However you could use SQL to MySQL tool available ***[here](http://download.cnet.com/SQL-To-MySQL-Converter/3000-10254_4-75693763.html)***.